# I was doing K-means Clustering, before that, each data in the database has to be assigned to an index. However, TypeError occurs, how to fix it?

Tags: python, k-means

Here's my code:

```
with connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = """
              SELECT `CPC-Current-DWPI`,`Assignee/Applicant First` FROM final.f01l_patent;
              """
        cursor.execute(sql)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        
        count = []
        ro=0
        for i in range(1,10):
            for j in result :
                if j['CPC - Current - DWPI.split()'][3]==str(i):
                    co+=1
            count.append(co)
            co=0
```

I know i can't index a tuple with a list, so i added .split() after CPC - Current - DWPI, but actually i have no idea with how to change lists into slices

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_19312\1811172777.py in <module>
     16         for i in range(1,10):
     17             for j in result :
---> 18                 if j['CPC - Current - DWPI.split()'][3]==str(i):
     19                     co+=1
     20             count.append(co)

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: This question would benefit from a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Can you edit your question to include a sample of what `result` includes?

Answer (score 1):

Your `result` is a list of `Tuple`s. Try replacing the string `'CPC - Current - DWPI.split()'` with the index (as an integer) of the item you want.